# How can i activate toggling on a button by clicking on it using bootstrap and HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Currently my buttons have hovering functionality and i want that it should remain there but when a user clicks on any of the text ("Water,Soil")then toggling functionality should be activated. Something as shown in this example but i cannot figure out how to incorporate this into my code with hovering: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#multiple-targets

I was able to implement simple toggle but i want hovering should also be there so user can hover over the text and when user clicks on it the buttons are toggled. How can i do that. Here is the fiddle and code:

https://jsfiddle.net/6u2g58qm/2/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#create_btn').on('click', function() {
    $('#create_tab').tab('show')
  })


  $('#login_btn').on('click', function() {
    $('#login_tab').tab('show')
  })

  $('#create_btn').on('click', function() {
    $('#create1_tab').tab('show')
  })
  $(".hover_btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  })


  $(".hover_btn").mouseenter(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tab1default").css("opacity", "1");
  })


  $(".hover_btn2").hover(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tab2default1").css("opacity", "1");
  })

  $(".hover_btn2").mouseleave(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tab2default").css("opacity", "0");
  })
  $(".hover_btn1").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  })


  $(".hover_btn1").mouseenter(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tab2default").css("opacity", "1");
  })

  $(".hover_btn2").mouseleave(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tab3default1").css("opacity", "0");
  })
    $(".hover_btn").mouseleave(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tab1default").css("opacity", "0");
  })
  
  $("#closeButton").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tab1default").css("opacity", "0");
  })
});
```

```css
#customTab a {
  padding: 0;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: baseline;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .btn {
    padding: 3px 6px;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .flex .panel-default {
    margin-right: 4px;
  }
  .flex .panel-default>.panel-heading {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .flex .panel-default>.panel-body .btn:last-child {
    margin-top: 4px;
  }
}

.btn-dark {
  background-color: #343a40;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn-dark:hover,
.btn.focus,
.btn:focus {
  color: #fff;
}

.btn.focus,
.btn:focus,
.btn:active,
.btn:hover,
.active>a .btn {
  color: #fff;
  background: blue;
}

.nav-tabs {
  border: none;
}

.hover_btn {
  background-image: url(air.jfif);
  background-size: cover;
  color: #000;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.hover_btn:hover {
  background-image: url(air.jfif);
  background-size: cover;
  color: #000;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main>

    <div class="container" id="customTab">
      <ul class="nav " style="display: flex; justify-content: space-around; border: none;">
        <li><a href="#tab1default" data-toggle="collapse" id="test"><span class="hover_btn">Water</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tab2default" data-toggle="collapse"><span class="hover_btn1">soil</span></a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="hover_btn2">
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab1default">
          <div class="flex ">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li data-toggle="tab"><span class="btn btn-info">1</span></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade hover_btn3" id="tab2default">
      <div class="flex">
        <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li><a href="#tab3default1" data-toggle="tab"><span class="btn btn-info">6</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the fiddle to make it easier to work with as there was quite a bit of unused html in there (for the demo at least). When you hover, it actually applies the classes to trigger the tab. When you mouse out the classes are removed. I did try and do this by using

```
$(tab).show("tab");
```

which did work but you cannot hide it in a similar way unfortunately. When you click on the tab I've used

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

to stop Bootstrap from handling the click and also set a variable that shows if we need to persist the tab.

Once you click on the tab, it will persist for the user and you will need to click it again to hide it. You can then continue to hover to show and hide it as before.

Hopefully this will be of use to you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var persist = false;

  $(".hover_btn").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();    
    persist = !persist;
  })
  
  $(".hover_btn").mouseenter(function(e) {   
    e.preventDefault();
        $("#tab1default").removeClass("collapse").addClass("fade").addClass("in").addClass("active");
  });

  $(".hover_btn").mouseleave(function(e) {   
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!persist)
    {
            $("#tab1default").addClass("collapse").removeClass("fade").removeClass("in").removeClass("active");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#customTab a {
  padding: 0;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: baseline;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .btn {
    padding: 3px 6px;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .flex .panel-default {
    margin-right: 4px;
  }
  .flex .panel-default>.panel-heading {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .flex .panel-default>.panel-body .btn:last-child {
    margin-top: 4px;
  }
}

.btn-dark {
  background-color: #343a40;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn-dark:hover,
.btn.focus,
.btn:focus {
  color: #fff;
}

.btn.focus,
.btn:focus,
.btn:active,
.btn:hover,
.active>a .btn {
  color: #fff;
  background: blue;
}

.nav-tabs {
  border: none;
}

.hover_btn {
  background-image: url(air.jfif);
  background-size: cover;
  color: #000;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.hover_btn:hover {
  background-image: url(air.jfif);
  background-size: cover;
  color: #000;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main>

    <div class="container" id="customTab">
      <ul class="nav " style="display: flex; justify-content: space-around; border: none;">
        <li><a href="#tab1default" data-toggle="collapse" id="test"><span class="hover_btn">Water</span></a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="hover_btn2">
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab1default">
          <div class="flex ">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li id="test" data-toggle="tab"><span class="btn btn-info">1</span></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade hover_btn3" id="tab2default">
      <div class="flex">
        <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li><a href="#tab3default1" data-toggle="tab"><span class="btn btn-info">6</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```